# Symbol info in .app file

Tags: iphone

i've recently released an app to the App store, i went to have a look at some crash logs in Organiser of my app downloaded from the app store and noticed that there is symbol info in my crash log - Shock Horror

I definitely remember setting some strip symbols flags when i built the distribution build (which was copied from release) so can't for the life of me work out how there is this symbol info there. I never shipped a .SYM file to apple just the .app. So whats going on. Surely apple would have warned me  about this wouldn't they??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK will automatically find the dSYM file if it is somewhere on your machine.  It uses Spotlight.

So you probably didn't delete the dSYM file, and when you opened up the crash log, it found the file and decoded it automatically for you.  Your code is safe!